# How to perform reduce_op on multiple dimensions at once?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a list of rank N tensors expressed as a rank N+1 tensor. For example, a list of 100 10x20 matrices as a rank 3 tensor with shape (100,10,20). I need to perform the same operations on each of those matrices: summing all the elements, mean and median of the values of the ith matrix, for each matrix.
Is it possible to do something like `tf.math.reduce_sum`, `tf.math.reduce_mean`, `tf.contrib.distributions.percentile`, along axis 0, but computing the whole matrix at once for each element along the 0 axis?

E.G.:

```
matricesList = tf.constant([[[1,1],[1,1]],
                           [[2,2],[2,2]]])

op = sum_matrices_along_axis(matrixList)
```

With expected `op = [4,8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple dimensions to the `axis` parameter of reduction operations:

```
import tensorflow as tf

matricesList = tf.constant([[[1, 1], [1, 1]],
                            [[2, 2], [2, 2]]])
matricesSum = tf.reduce_sum(matricesList, axis=[1, 2])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(matricesSum))
    # [4 8]
```

Even if you do not know the number of dimensions in advance, you can still reduce "all but the first" dimensions:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# The number of dimensions of tensorsList is unspecified
tensorsList = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
# Dimensions from one to the last one
reduceDims = tf.range(1, tf.rank(tensorsList))
tensorsSum = tf.reduce_sum(tensorsList, axis=reduceDims)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    matrices = [[[1, 1], [1, 1]],
                [[2, 2], [2, 2]]]
    print(sess.run(tensorsSum, feed_dict={tensorsList: matrices}))
    # [4 8]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know it's possible to pass multiple axis, but above all I totally missed that I can simply flatten the elements of the N+1 rank tensor in an array, and compute all the operations on a matrix of the flattened tensors, since I don't mind the dimensionality of them.

Comment: @LolAsdOmgWtfAfk Yes that's right, you can also do `tf.reduce_sum(tf.reshape(tensorsList, [tf.shape(tensorsList)[0], -1]), axis=1)`.

Comment: Sorry, N rank tensor*
I will try the fastest option, thanks :)